# Should SO renumber questions that are abused by spammers?

Tags: discussion, spam

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139238/session-id-in-url-and-or-cookie). The nortorious "ugg boot spammer" keeps returning to this question (if you have 10K powers you can see the deleted spam posts).

Obviously, some spammer has this bookmarked and keeps coming back to create new accounts and post garbage. Can this question be renumbered, killing its permalink? Would this help the problem? Perhaps if our boot pushing friend gets a 404 he'll just go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking permalinks punishes everyone. If we were gonna go that far, then [voyager's Closing suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26180/should-so-renumber-questions-that-are-abused-by-spammers/26182#26182) would at least allow folks to still *find* the question, even if they couldn't respond.

Answer (score 2):

What about closing the question?

Of course, if there are more than one question that are being spammed, may be we should simply block the user/IP block.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the question. It's just been hijacked by a spammer.

Comment: @Jon B: I know, but if the spammer derails the question into an advertisment, then that will be really bad. I preffer the question be kept stale and without new answers than the question having to be deleted. But of course, if it could be moved, it would be good enough (I guess). May be a feature request for a `belongs on stackoverflow` close reason in stackoverflow (for 10k+s, I guess)?

Answer (score 1):

Can't diamond mods lock a post so it can't receive answers without closing it? That would seem the right answer, with a comment as to why the question is locked.

Changing the number is, at best, a short-term fix.

And again, IP bans are probably a good idea, too (unless the spammer is using multiple IPs, which they probably are).

Comment: Off-topic, but can someone who's a diamond mod on any trilogy site shoot me an e-mail? I just got those privs on an SE site and would like a few pointers regarding what some of the tools are for. There's a lot more than I expected to see there!

Comment: Locking prevents modifications to *the post itself*, but a locked question can still be answered. Closing + locking is necessary to prevent both.

Comment: Thanks; wasn't aware of that. Yep, then close+lock is probably the right answer.